# Encontrar la moda de una matriz (lenguaje c)

Tags: c

Tengo este programa y quiero sacar cual es la moda (el numero que más se repite) de los valores enteros introducidos. Hasta el momento he llegado al siguiente programa, pero todavía no encuentro una forma de que me muestre solo la moda, sino que me muestra todos los números que se repitieron. ¿Que puedo hacer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int mat[4][4], f, c, moda, contador=0;

    for (f = 0; f < 4; f++)
        for(c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        {
            printf("Da valor: ");
            scanf("%d", &mat[f][c]);
        }

    for (f = 0; f < 4; f++)
        for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        {
            if (mat[f] == mat[c])
            {
                moda = mat[f][c];
                printf("la moda es:%d", moda);
                {
                    contador=contador+1;
                }
            }
            if (contador > moda)
            {

            }
            moda = contador;
            contador = 0;
        }

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema trata de dada una colección de número enteros, almacenados en una matriz N*M, ver que número se repite más veces. Entonces una posible solución sería obtener un par donde indique el número en si y las veces que se repite. Con esto, podemos tener:

1. Una **estructura con dos enteros**, un entero para el número y un entero para las veces que se repite dicho número.
2. En principio no sabemos el número de estructuras que vamos a tener, podemos tener una (si el elemento se repite siempre) o tantas como elementos hay en la matriz, por esta razón utilizaremos una **lista dinámica**, ya que no sabemos los elementos que vamos a tener. La inserción en la lista es indiferente en este caso, la hacemos por la cabeza.

La estructura de la lista:

```
struct repeticiones_numero {
    int n;
    int veces;
};

struct lista {
    struct repeticiones_numero d;
    struct lista *sig;
};
```

Podemos almacenar, los elementos de la matriz en una array unidimensional de N*M, una vez tengamos el array, recorremos y creamos los nodos de la lista si el elemento no existe aún en la lista, en el momento que exista lo que hacemos es sumar 1 a las veces que se repite. Por ejemplo, para una matriz de 3x3, tendremos:

- **ARRAY[9] = {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3}**
- **Lista obtenida: {[d.n=1,d.veces=4],[d.n=2,d.veces=3], [d.n=3,d.veces=2]}**

Una vez tenemos esta lista, basta recorrerla para obtener el máximo de la propiedad veces, para posteriormente con este valor máximo obtener el número que tiene esa propiedad veces.
En este algoritmo si hay valores que se repiten las mismas veces solo devuelve uno de ellos. Bastaría con crear otra lista para terminar y añadir los elementos que cumplen que las repeticiones son iguales a máximo número de repeticiones.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3
#define M 3
#define LEN N*M

int main(void)
{
    int mat[N][M], f, c, moda;
    int elem,i;
    int esta;
    int vec[LEN];
    int max = 0;
    
    struct repeticiones_numero {
        int n;
        int veces;
    };
    
    struct lista_repeticiones {
        struct repeticiones_numero d;
        struct lista_repeticiones *sig;
    };
    
    i = 0;
    for(f=0; f<N; f++) {
        for(c=0; c<M; c++) {
            printf("Da valor: ");
            scanf("%d", &mat[f][c]);
            vec[i] = mat[f][c];
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    
    struct lista_repeticiones *l, *aux = NULL;
    for (i=0;i<LEN;i++){
        elem = vec[i];
        esta = 0;
        while (aux != NULL){
            //Si el elemento ya está en la lista
            if (elem == aux->d.n){
                aux->d.veces = aux->d.veces + 1;
                esta = 1;
            }
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        //Si el elemento no está en la lista
        if (esta == 0){
            struct lista_repeticiones *nodo = (struct lista_repeticiones *) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
            nodo->d.n = elem;
            nodo->d.veces = 1;
            nodo->sig = l;
            l = nodo;
        }
        aux = l;
    }
    
    //Calculamos el número máximo de veces que se repite un elemento
    aux = l;
    while (aux != NULL){
        if (aux->d.veces > max){
            max = aux->d.veces;
        }
        aux = aux->sig;
    }
    
    //Asignamos a moda el último elemento que se repite más veces
    aux = l;
    while (aux != NULL){
        if (aux->d.veces == max){
            moda = aux->d.n;
        }
        aux= aux->sig;
    }
    
    printf("La moda de los datos introducidos es: %d\n", moda);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sugerencia menor: sería más adecuado que el `struct datos` tuviese un nombre más definitorio, ya que por su nombre actual no se sabe qué datos contiene, o qué representa. Alternativas serían `struct numero` o `struct repeticionesNumero` (o `struct repeticiones_numero`). Lo mismo con la lista: `struct listaRepeticiones` o `struct lista_repeticiones`, o algo similar.

Comment: Tienes razón con lo que dices, he realizado el cambio en el código para mejorar la compresión.